# Adding an array to a combo box

Tags: java, swing, object, arraylist, jcombobox

I want to add an array to an existing combobox without passing the array object as a argument in the constructor. Is there perhaps a way to do this by using a method?

Something like the following

```
Object[] comboBoxDisplay = myAnimals.toArray();
    comboAnimals.add(comboBoxDisplay);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use a [`DefaultComboBoxModel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultComboBoxModel.html) to construct the [`JComboBox`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#JComboBox%28javax.swing.ComboBoxModel%29) it provides an `addElement()` method.

You'd have to call that from a loop, rather than as a single statement, but then, that's why they pay us 'the big bucks'.  ;)

Comment: You can also do: 
DefaultComboBoxModel newModel  = new DefaultComboBoxModel(myAnimals.toArray());
comboAnimals.setModel(newModel);

Comment: @AKJ  I considered that possibility, but it will wipe out the current entries in the combo.  The OP wants to *add* to the *current* entries (by my interpretation of the question).